# How to send consecutive get requests

Tags: android, http-get

I want to write a function that listens a server by sending get requests reqularly. The next request shouldn't be sent to server until a response is received from the first request. To simulate this, I write the following code which sends consecutive get request to server 5 times:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        tv.setText(retrieve("http://www.mydomain.com/http.php?key=" + i));
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

"String retrieve(String url) { ... }" is function that returns content of url, in this case just a number sent by the following PHP file ("http.php"):

```
<?php
sleep(1);
echo $_GET['key']+1;
?>
```

Although I put 1 second sleep to see values on my android app, the only thing I see is "5" after some seconds. So are these 5 requests are asyn or are they consecutive or is there another problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the method onCreate is executed only once before you get to see anything, thats probably why you can only see 5 (the last one). Also, you shouldn't do network calls from there since that will block the UI main thread for a while and probably provoke a force close in your app.

You should implement a method to run in background. Something similar to this:

```
private int i;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  i = 0
  new ServerRetreiveTask().execute("http://www.mydomain.com/http.php?key=" + i);
}

private class ServerRetreiveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String urls) {
         return retrieve(url);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
         if (i<5){
            i++:
            new ServerRetreiveTask().execute("http://www.mydomain.com/http.php?key=" + i);
         }
     }
 }
```

Read this document for more info about asynchronous task http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Alternative way using Threads (not recommended):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String response;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    response = retrieve("http://www.mydomain.com/http.php?key=" + i);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            tv.setText(response);

                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: but I want it to be synchoronus, I mean, second request shouldn't be sent until first response is received from server (am I right?). Thus, is a loop like this OK?

Comment: The option i gave you is the recommended one. If you read the code you can see the method onPostExecute. This is called when the request is done, so it will work as you want. 

You can also do a loop in your way using Threads:

Comment: Thank you for the solution, that's the best way as you said... I also wonder your idea about listening a server? I think this http get is not a real solution.

Comment: It you want to get data from a server in a regular basis i would recommend you to implement a service that would run on background. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html